# How can I find Xamarin.Android v4 Support in my Properties?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm watching a Xamarin tutorial on YouTube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Jx7ZNZL9dk&list=PLCuRg51-gw5VqYchUekCqxUS9hEZkDf6l and I've hit a brick using Visual Studio.

I've successfully downloaded Xamarin and Xamarin Android Player for the phone emulators.

However, in the video, it tells me to change the **Minimum Android Target** to one of the many Xamarin.AndroiD v4.1 Support options. I have not got any of the Xamarin options in my drop down list.

[This dropdown menu in my Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpyoY.png)

Perhaps I haven't installed something that enables the Xamarin options to be visible. Help, please

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the other API levels that you want as your `minSdkVersion` inside your `Android SDK Manager` to see more in this dropdown. https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/ide/launch_sdk_manager/#Launch_SDK_Manager_from_Visual_Studio

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your SDK Manager and your dropdown?